# pkg cannot find module '@... when i use _moduleAliases?

Tags: node.js

pkg cannot find module '@... when i use _moduleAliases?
I use

```
   "module-alias": "^2.2.2",
```

How to fix this problem?

```json
  "_moduleAliases": {
    "@root": "./",
    "@": "./"
  },
```

```
// i will import the file like this:
const { jwt } = require('@/config')
```

Answer (score 0):

in the top of your main script you should add `require('module-alias/register');`

Comment: I have this code in my index.js. but "pkg" still dont work,and if i use it in lerna project, I should set   "_moduleAliases" in my root package.json